# Tradingview's auto fit scale function: exclude drawings of an indicator

Tags: scale, pine-script

I've got an indicator which automatically compresses the whole price chart on the y-scale, so I have to leave it invisible most of the time.
Even a doubleclick on the y-scale (chart auto fit function) includes all visible indicators.
Is there any way to prevent one or all indicators from doing that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

ohhh... I've just found the answer ... a simple right click on the y-scale brings ups the context menu with an "scale price chart only" option!! Hope this also helps someone else :-)

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question and helping the community! This freed me from a lot of frustration.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It was driving me crazy, haha.

Answer (score 2):

The current version of TradingView has one finer level for displaying. Selecting 'Auto' and 'Scale Price Chart Only' is the current right-click option to keep indicators from shrinking your y-scale. 'Scale Price Chart Only' seems to work as well (slightly different scaling), personally not interested in figuring out the difference. :-)

But thanks to the original poster, googled my way here to find a solution and leaving with one!

Comment: I do not see what this is contributing in addition to the post you say "thanks" for. Could you make it more obvious? That would avoid the impression that this is purely "thanks" only, which would mean that it should be flagged and deleted as "not an answer".