# Function that doesn't make plot zoom out

Tags: pine-script

I wrote a function that has the functionality I am looking for. However, if I run it, the plot zooms out to show me the entire function, instead of zooming onto the candles.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here:
[Tradingview's auto fit scale function: exclude drawings of an indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60223688/tradingviews-auto-fit-scale-function-exclude-drawings-of-an-indicator)

"ohhh... I've just found the answer ... a simple right click on the y-scale brings ups the context menu with an "scale price chart only" option!! Hope this also helps someone else :-)"